# Vuejs - How to change the text inside {{ }}

Tags: vue.js, datatable, string-interpolation

I've been building a data table recently and stuck at somewhere. I want my columns to be clickable to be able to display the rows in ascending and descending orders. When they are being displayed in ascending orders I want to show my `arrow_upward` icon and otherwise I want to show `arrow_downward` icon. Here is what I have done so far...

```
data () {
    return {
      arrow_upward: 'arrow_upward',
      arrow_downward: 'arrow_downward',
    }
   }
```

and by the way, here is my usage of my Material Icons...

```
<span class="table-icons">arrow_upward</span>
```

I tried this one first;

```
<span class="table-icons" v-if="col == sortColumn">{{arrow_upward}}</span>
```

Basically I say, if it's sorted by column, show the `arrow_upward` icon. And here is my problem. How am I going to change inside the `{{ }}` everytime the column is clicked. It should work like a toggle and the interpolation tags should change between `arrow_upward` and `arrow_downward`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following conditional rendering :

```
 <span class="table-icons" >{{col == sortColumn?'arrow_upward':'arrow_downward'}}</span>
```

and no need to define them as data properties.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I need.